# Remove (.) from decimal values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to remove . from all decimal value from my query output like if i use

```
select(32.00) output should come 3200
select(32.50) output should come 3250
select(32.05) output should come 3205
```

Is there is any function present to give me this output i dont want 3200.00 as output
if anyone know plz tell me how ?

Comment: You really should specify what data type your 32.05 is. Is it `money`,  `decimal`, `real`, `double`, ...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could multiply by 100 and cast to an integer:

```
=> select cast(32.00*100 as integer);
 int4 
------
 3200
```

That will give you an integer. If your values aren't the `decimal(n,2)` that they appear to be, then you might want to pull out [`round`, `floor`, or `ceil`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) to make your desired rounding or truncation explicit:

```
=> select floor(23.025 * 100), ceil(23.025 * 100), round(23.025 * 100);
 floor | ceil | round 
-------+------+-------
  2302 | 2303 |  2303
```

Comment: One would think this would not work if the value was 32.001 but apparently it does

Comment: @ertx: The cast-to-int will work but it will truncate. I added a couple more options in case the incoming data isn't the `decimal(n,2)` that it appears to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT replace(CAST(your_field AS text),'.','')
FROM your_table
```

Comment: @mu is too short: is this better? Thanks :)